# Remove Toast calls from Android using ProGuard

Tags: android, configuration

I want to remove the calls of Toast in my AndroidProject. Th ecalls to Log.d I've removed using the following ProGuard rule in my `proguard-rules.pro` file in AndroidStudio.

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

Now I want to add a rule to the same file to remove th calls to Toast in release mode. How does this rule looks like? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.widget.Toast {
    public static *** makeText(...);
    public *** show();
}
```